# ip forwarding to remotely connect to a socket listening to localhost only?

Tags: ip, socket

I must transfer data from PC1 to PC2 using a specific port, but the socket opened on PC2 only listens to local host. Is there a way to "trick" the socket into accepting the connection from PC1?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ssh` with port forwarding.

E.g.

```
ssh <remotehost> -L 1234:<target>:5678
```

this command connects you to remotehost and connects your local port 1234 to the remote port 5678 on the server named `<target>`.

In your case `<target>` would be `localhost` as you directly connect to the target host.

Comment: This is a clever answer but unfortunately it will not work for my situation. The data I have to send over tcp are specific packets built in a c++ application, which means I need a server-side solution.

Comment: If your server side supports ssh with port forearding then this solution works as your client opens a port at 1234 and on the server side ssh connects to port 5678. I don't see why this should not work.

Comment: The OP wanted to connect to a port that is bound to localhost. This solution won't work.

Answer (score 0):

If your application binds to localhost the only way to forward that port is to NAT your requests to your loopback interface. Hence you you are able achieve this by doing the following:

**Add iptables roule:**

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 1234 -j DNAT --to 127.0.0.1:5678
```

Now every request coming at port 1234 on the target machine, will be forwarded to 127.0.0.1:5678.

Then don't forget to do the following:

**Enable IP forwarding:**

```
echo 1 /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

**Enable route localnet:**

```
echo 1 /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/route_localnet
```